# Cannot call senderror() after response has been committed Tomcat Spring MVC

Tags: spring, rest

If I am returning a Employee object in my controller class, I get a response from my REST service. But if I am trying to return a List, then I frequently get this error:

Error:cannot call senderror() after the response has been committed
(Also atttached the image)
[image]
I am using Eclipse, tomcat, maven and making a spring REST service.

Here is my Controller class code snippetwhich is returning Employee, and everything is fine and I can see my JSON data on browser. But when I change Employee to List as my new return type, I receive the following error and my Eclipse also hangs for few minutes. I think my problem could have to do with the JSON convertor. Please help.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/emp")
public class EMPController {

@Autowired
EmployeeService empservice;
@RequestMapping("byname3/{name}")
@ResponseBody
public Employee getByName(@PathVariable String name) {
    System.out.println("Inside getByName()..successfully..EMPController");
    .....
    ......
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spice.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spice.daoImpl" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spice.serviceImpl " />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />   <!-- tHIS HELPS IN AUTOMATIC JSON-TO-JAVA AND VICE VERSA CONVERTUION -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
        <property name="username" value="tiwari"></property>
        <property name="password" value="tiwari"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <!-- eARLIER i WAS USING org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean -->
        <!-- BUT THIS LEADS TO SOME CACHE PROVIDER CLASS NOT FOUND EXCEPTION -->
        <!-- ALSO THIS AnnotationSessionFactoryBean IS NOW REPLACED BY LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

         <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.spice.beans.Employee</value>
                <value>com.spice.beans.Address</value>
            </list>
        </property>


        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

    <bean id="transactionManager"  
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <!-- THIS CLASS IS COMPATIBLE WITH ABOVE VERSIONS OF SPRING AND HIBERNATE  -->  
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />  
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error:cannot call senderror() after the response has been committed
>   (Also atttached the image)

This error is an aftermath of a different error. The server encountered a main exception with your application and hence it tried to call HttpServletResponse#sendError(), which throws IllegalStateException in turn.